# Android build fails in Jenkins - because of evaluating project: app

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, continuous-integration

I am running the following gradle script in my Jenkins android job - `./gradlew app:connectedQADebugAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.size=large`

And it always fails because of this problem `What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
 Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.google.gms.google-services']
    No such property: applicationVariants for class: java.lang.String`

The same script works when I run from android studio on the same machine.

However when I run `/gradlew app:connectedQADebugAndroidTest` it works. Can anyone please help me understand and solve the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Is your jenkins workspace up to date with your Android Studio working directory? In the jenkins job, are you "executing shell" or using a gradle plugin?

Comment: I'm using 'executing shell' not gradle plugin. Logs show that latest gradle version is used in jenkins and it's up to date with android studion

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was unclear. I was asking if you tested the Android Studio IDE in the Jenkins workspace. Typically, people run Android Studio on their machine in their own folder structure and have Jenkins run jobs in a standard (typically shared/remote) workspace.  It's certainly possible to point Studio to your Jenkins workspace for testing; I wanted to make sure that's what you had already tried.  If I'm understand correctly, you're saying 1) running the gradle task on the command line works; 2) running it in studio works; and 3) it fails only when running via Jenkins

Comment: Thanks for the help. But it works in Jenkins now as well. It was a problem of syntax in my script in Jenkins shell...